# Equipotential inside a conductor ring, but how do I determine the value?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

I was mapping the potential lines of 2 cylindrical electrodes - one at 0 V, the other at 5 V. I have a metallic ring midway between the 2 electrodes. I know that the electric field inside the ring is 0, so the potential inside the ring is constant.

What I can't understand is why the potential inside the ring has the value of 2.5 V.

Can somebody explain to me how to obtain the potential in this case?

Comment: Hi Fernando Slipperpt Mendon&#231;a and welcome to Physics.SE! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I was mapping the potential lines of 2 cilindric eletrodes. I have a metalic ring in the middle (middle distance) of the 2 eletrodes. i know that the eletric field inside the ring is 0, so the potential inside the ring is constant. But why it has the value of 2.5V?

Comment: If you were to edit your original post it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your situation looks like this:

[image]

The medium surrounding the electrodes is water - a conductor (but not a very good one). This means that a current will flow - more current will flow where the electric field is strongest.

Now the conducting ring in the middle will make sure that the potential anywhere in the grey region is the same (because the current would flow around the ring to make it so). That means that current from the 5 V conductor will try to flow to the ring, around the ring, and to the 0 V conductor.

Now by the symmetry of the situation, all the current from the 5V to the ring must equal the current flowing from the ring to the 0V electrode. And if the current flowing is the same, then the electric field must be the same. And if the electric field is the same, then the potential difference between 0V and ring must be the same as the potential difference between ring and 5V. And that means that the ring is at a potential exactly midway between the other two.

If it was any other value, the current would become asymmetrical; at which point charge would build up, and this charge buildup would change the potential. Until V was 2.5 V...